# When added a new row timestamp column issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table on the SQL Server, which is updated if someone send a specific sms message to a specific number.

What i did is i entered a new table, which is a timestamp one.
Now, the issue is, when a new row is added i get this in the timestamp value:

```
<binary data>
```

Why does this happen?
What should i do?

Thanks!

Comment: I just added add column time_added timestamp, i mean something like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to record the date and time when a row was inserted use a `datetime` (or `datetime2`, if using SQL Server 2008 or later) column with a default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tab add time_added datetime2
ALTER TABLE tab add constraint DF_tab_time_added
    DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) for time_added
```

`timestamp` is a (badly named) synonym for [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), which has no relationship with an actual date and time:

> `timestamp` is the synonym for the `rowversion` data type
>
> The `rowversion` data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use `datetime` datatype for the column, which is being used for capturing the current/updating/inserting date or time.

`TIMESTAMP` stores the version of the updates/insertions.

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME>
ADD CONSTRAINT <CONSTRAINT_NAME> DEFAULT getdate() FOR <COLUMN_NAME>
```